# Are there any Perl's CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser) alternatives for Python?

Tags: python, error-handling, cgi, error-reporting

I sometimes `use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser)` in Perl CGI programming to transform fatal errors —including compile-time errors— into an HTML error page containing the error message. This is particularly useful in situations where errors aren't log, or when the logs are difficult to access.

Are there any similar handy methods for Python?

Comment: Thank you. I corrected it. :)

Comment: Read about [module-cgitb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgitb.html#module-cgitb)